# postgreSQL 8.4 and 9.3

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, centos7, centos6

I'm having some problem in restoring a DB backup pg8.4 (.dump) into pg9.3

It works ok when I restore the 8.4 to the 9.2 but for some reason doesn't work in 9.3

The setup are:

Centos 6 pg8.4

Centos 7 pg9.2

Centos 7 pg9.3

All the server comes with Plesk, pg9.2 is installed through Plesk while the 9.3 from the official [site](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/)

All the server also use Postgis (2.1.8 in 9.2 and 9.3 and an older version in 8.4)

I tried to restore the dump file through Pgadmin and through terminal, what is the difference between 9.2 and 9.3 why I can't restore the data?

Can be because of the 9.2 data folder is in `/var/lib/pgsql/data` and if installed through the official site is in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data`?

these are some of the error I have:

```
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE OWNED BY "public.mordersl_ogc_fid_seq"
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.mordersp"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 160; 1259 18553 TABLE mordersp postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "mordersp" already exists
    Command was: CREATE TABLE mordersp (
    ogc_fid integer NOT NULL,
    wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,27700),
    item_ref numeric(254,0)...
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.mordersp_ogc_fid_seq"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 159; 1259 18551 SEQUENCE mordersp_ogc_fid_seq postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "mordersp_ogc_fid_seq" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SEQUENCE mordersp_ogc_fid_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE OWNED BY "public.docstore_ogc_fid_seq"
pg_restore: creating VIEW "public.geography_columns"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 143; 1259 17626 VIEW geography_columns postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "geography_columns" already exists
    Command was: CREATE VIEW geography_columns AS
SELECT current_database() AS f_table_catalog, n.nspname AS f_table_schema, c.relname AS f_t...
pg_restore: creating VIEW "public.geometry_columns"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 144; 1259 17730 VIEW geometry_columns postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" already exists
    Command was: CREATE VIEW geometry_columns AS
SELECT (current_database())::character varying(256) AS f_table_catalog, (n.nspname)::charact...
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.mapscheds"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 154; 1259 18517 TABLE mapscheds postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "mapscheds" already exists
    Command was: CREATE TABLE mapscheds (
    ogc_fid integer NOT NULL,
    wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,27700),
    msid numeric(254,0),
 ...
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.mapscheds_ogc_fid_seq"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 153; 1259 18515 SEQUENCE mapscheds_ogc_fid_seq postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "mapscheds_ogc_fid_seq" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SEQUENCE mapscheds_ogc_fid_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE OWNED BY "public.mapscheds_ogc_fid_seq"
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.mapschedsback"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 165; 1259 191782 TABLE mapschedsback postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "mapschedsback" already exists
    Command was: CREATE TABLE mapschedsback (
    ogc_fid integer,
    wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,27700),
    msid numeric(254,0),
    ms...
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.minv"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 156; 1259 18529 TABLE minv postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "minv" already exists
    Command was: CREATE TABLE minv (
    ogc_fid integer NOT NULL,
    wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,27700),
    item_ref numeric(254,0),
  ...
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.minv_ogc_fid_seq"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 155; 1259 18527 SEQUENCE minv_ogc_fid_seq postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "minv_ogc_fid_seq" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SEQUENCE minv_ogc_fid_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

I tried to restore without creating the table before and after creating the table.

this is a part of the script:

```
  -- Table: ordersl

-- DROP TABLE ordersl;

CREATE TABLE ordersl
(
  ogc_fid serial NOT NULL,
  wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,27700),
  item_ref numeric(254,0),
  order_ref character varying(32),
  locality character varying(30),
  ....
  pm_id numeric(254,0),
  order_id numeric(254,0),
  order_doc character varying(254),
  ms_grid character varying(20),
  CONSTRAINT ordersl_pk PRIMARY KEY (ogc_fid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE ordersl
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Index: ordersl_geom_idx

-- DROP INDEX ordersl_geom_idx;

CREATE INDEX ordersl_geom_idx
  ON ordersl
  USING gist
  (wkb_geometry);
```

Comment: How are you restoring, what exactly is the problem? Any specific error messages?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Right, that's expected.

You have to dump the 8.4 database with the `pg_dump` executable from 9.3.

9.3 knows how to dump an 8.4 database so that the dump loads in 9.3.

Comment: on the server I have PG8.4 I don't have PG9.3, I'm speaking that the 8.4 backup in another server with PG9.2 works and in 9.3 no

Comment: Your description is slightly confusing, so sorry if I got it wrong. The bottom line is: if you want to restore with 9.3, you have to dump with 9.3. That is the supported way. If anything else happens to work, you are lucky.

Comment: well..I'm told you that I can restore the 8.4 dump, created with 8.4 into 9.2, and the 2 databases are in 2 different servers where in one I have just 8.4 and in the other just 9.2. `pg_dump`is retro-compatible so should work. the proof is that works in 9.2. the problem is 9.3 that I don't understand why doesn't work

Comment: If a 8.4 dump restores into 9.2, you were just lucky. `pg_dump` is *not* backwards compatible in the way you think. Believe me or look it up in the documentation. It is to be expected that a 8.4 dump won't restore into 9.3.

Comment: lucky or not it works and I can restore anything I want, I think I'm going to restore the 8.4 into the 9.2 and then make a backup of the 9.2 and restore it into the 9.3...it's a bit of work but it seems the only way

Comment: If you want to make your life hard by using an unsupported way when the supported way is even simpler, go ahead. If you dump the 9.2 database with 9.2 `pg_dump`, importing it into the 9.3 database *might* fail just the same. Why do you have that strong aversion against dumping the 8.4 database with 9.3 `pg_dump`?

Comment: because 1) I don't have pg 9.3 in that servers 2) I just want to backup the data before to reimage the whole server. I don' want to waste time into install and configure another version of PG

Comment: It doesn't take a lot of time to install PostgreSQL. But you don't have to do that! You can use the 9.3 installation from the new server to dump the 8.4 database (use the `-h` option of `pg_dump` to connect to a remote server).

Comment: I didn't think about it, it could be an option :)